# Find the active form element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I create the form every time a pop-up modal is opened:

```
<form method="post" data-asset-share-id="download-modal"
    class="ui modal cmp-modal-download--wrapper cmp-modal transition visible active"
    style="top: 151px; display: block !important;">

        "Some html"

</form>
```

I want to know if the pop-up modal is active using jQuery.

Comment: which modal ? bootstrap ?

Comment: semantic-ui modal

Comment: "*I want to know if transition visible active in jquery*" — what?!

Comment: if pop up modal is in active state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event handler for the modal, there are [custom events in semantic-ui modal](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/settings). In your case, you can use `onVisible` or `onShow` event.

```
$('.modal').on('onVisible', function(){
   // your code here
})
```